# Magento Caching Custom Images

Tags: performance, magento, caching

I am using the avalanche theme and make use of the homepage slider.

The images are added to the site via a section in the admin panel and they are stored in

```
media/banners/default/slidex.jpg
```

I notice that these images are not being cached and loaded directly from their location.  Is there any way to include images such as these in the magento image cache in order to reduce load time?

As these are large banner images you would expect them to take longer to load, however in the pingdom tools analysis for my home page it indicates that the server side wait is much longer than the time it actually takes to receive the files.

Comment: Assumably if it's being loaded from that location, it's not being resized, if it's not being resized, how would caching help? It would just be a copy of the image in a different location on the hard-drive. In your tests was the server side wait specifically for the image request? If so, there's likely no optimisation to be made with regards to your Magento application, you would need to optimise your server setup. Introducing a reverse proxy such as Varnish would likely improve this performance substantially.

Comment: I thought caching did things other than resize...quality for example.  Yes the server side wait was what was taking the time....I will look at Varnish

Comment: @MatthewDolman Man u need CDN or cloudfont like thing to reduce the load time. The magento product image caching is to reduce the Reize time on each request. e.g. If there is an image with 50x50 then there is no need to resize it again on the next request.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem witch was caching a resized brand logo slider images.

I solved the problem by storing the resized images in media/product/cache/resized_images - with *Mage::getBaseDir('media')*. So, you just need to check if the cached image exists before regenerating it.

Everything in this folder is deleted when flushing image cache in admin.

I hope it helps.